# R, optimizing code to find the largest palindrome from multiplying two 3-digit numbers

Tags: r, optimization

I am working to solve Project Euler Problem 4.  While I have seen other questions on stackoverflow regarding this problem, I haven't seen any written in R.  The question is as follows:

"A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.  Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers."

I have written two functions to this end.  The first, `genNums`, generates the products of all the 3-digit numbers that could provide a potential solution.  the second, `findPalindromes`, goes through the list generated by the first function to find the products that are palindromes.  It also uses the `max` function to identify the largest palindrome in the list.

I'm a beginner programmer, and this code is highly inefficient. R is able to get through genNums just fine, but it can't finish off the findPalindromes function.  It doesn't throw any errors-- but it also can't work through the function and produce an answer.  I think my for loop in `findPalindromes` may be structured incorrectly, but I'm not sure.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
genNums <- function() {
  empty <- list()
  l <- c(100:999) #the question is only interested in three digit numbers.  Lowest three digit number is 100.
  for (i in l){
    result <- i * l  #,multiply each item in list l by list l to obtain the set of possible products
    empty <-  c(empty, result)  #concatonate the multiplication results into a list
  }#end for loop
  return(empty) 
}#end function

findPalindromes <- function(){
  full <- genNums()
  pals <- list()
  print("I made it through genNums")
  for (i in full){
    if (i == rev(i)){
    pals <- c(pals, i)
    }
  }#end for loop

  maximum <-  max(pals)
  print(c("The largest palindrome is " + maximu))
}#end function
```

Comment: If you just want people to review your working code, then you should post to  [codereview.se], not Stack Overflow. If you are having a specific problem, you should be able to describe the output you expect. Describe where you are having trouble. Just asking someone to solve a Project Euler problem for you isn't really a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 2):

```
is.palindrome <- function(x) {
        digits <- strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]]
        all(digits == rev(digits))
}
```

Find largest 3 digit palindrome:

```
all_prods <- outer(1:999, 1:999)
p <- all_prods
p[] <- sapply(p, is.palindrome)
mx <- all_prods == max(all_prods[!!p])

col(all_prods)[mx]
[1] 913 993

#Test
913*993
[1] 906609
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a string reversing function like this one:

```
strReverse <- function(x)
        sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), rev), paste, collapse="")
```

Then you need a function that determines if a number is a palindrome:

```
isPal <- function(y){
        x <- sprintf("%d",y)
        strReverse(x)==x
}
```

You then simply create your combinations product:

```
productList <- combn(1000, 2, function(x){x[[1]]*x[[2]]})
```

Apply to it your isPal function:

```
palList <- sapply(productList, function(p){isPal(p)})
```

And select the biggest palindrome:

```
max(productList[palList])
```